# Does Mail.app send or can request read receipts?

Tags: mail.app

I was wondering whether Mail.app is able to send read receipts (or maybe it does silently?) or create emails that require those?

I know such a feature is available in Outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this using Mail on Snow Leopard connected to Exchange 2005.

There is no ability to set a request to receive read receipts.

Reading an email sent from Outlook in Windows to mail on Snow Leopard with a read recipt requested, does not send a read receipt.

Lion may vary.

Comment: I have tested with newer Exchange servers on Lion and it seems to be consistent across the range - Mail.app neither request nor sends back read receipts.

Answer (score 0):

**Mail.app** can be told to [ask for read receipts](http://www.mackungfu.org/make-mail-app-request-read-receipts), you can use [Mail Receipt](http://miln.eu/mailreceipt/) to set up the required custom headers:

[image: Screen shot of Miln Mail Request]

Mail Receipt works for macOS versions before 10.14. With macOS 10.14, Apple introduced new security requirements that limited third party access to Mail's preferences.

### How Read Receipts work

To ask for a read receipt an additional header needs to be added to your outgoing e-mails. **Mail.app** supports custom headers through a default called `UserHeaders`.

When changing defaults, be sure to quit **Mail.app** before altering the default. Afterwards relaunch **Mail.app** and test any changes.

### Setting a Read Receipt Header

Customise and use the following **Terminal.app** command to set a `Disposition-Notification-To` header:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Disposition-Notification-To" = "YOUR NAME <YOUR@EMAILADDRESS.COM>"; }'
```

#### Removing Custom Headers

To stop asking for read receipts, delete the `UserHeaders` preferences with the command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.mail UserHeaders
```